# Indentation behaviour for Bootstrap input fields

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have form. Inside two inputs - Date and Time (with ids resDate and resTime respectively). I don't understand, why Bootstrap adds indentation for inputs? Why input fields aren't on the same level as radios and reserve button in this case? Code is here: http://codepen.io/socialodima/pen/zZrNMB

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="resDate" name="resDate" placeholder="Date">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="resTime" name="resTime" placeholder="Time">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all the `col-*` values has a CSS property `padding-left:15px` and `padding-right:15px`. The parent `div.col-sm-10` which is wrapping your inputs already has the above said `paddings` and above that the `inputs` are wrapped in one more `div` having class `col-sm-4` which again adds more `padding` to the same. So I would suggest either write your own style to remove padding from `div` or keep them outside the `div.col-sm-4` or you can remove the class assigned to the `div`. My suggestion would be to remove padding with extra `CSS` as below:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <label class="control-label" for="resDate"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 no-pad">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resDate" name="resDate" placeholder="Date">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  <label class="control-label" for="resTime"></label>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 no-pad">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="resTime" name="resTime" placeholder="Time">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.no-pad{
   padding:0px;
}
```

**Note** - I've added `.no-pad` class to the `div.col-sm-4` which wraps `inputs`

Here's the **[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/JWGNag)**

Answer (score 0):

Your col-sm-4 class is adding padding to the right and left of the field.  You can use CSS to override it or make another class or id for that field and specify 0px on padding-left.

```
.col-sm-4 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

You should use a new class or ID for this though.

[SolutionImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBpJQ.png)